# Host a json file that is outside the war file in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, web, configuration, server.xml

I have a json file that is in webapps folder of tomcat but outside my project folder. I need this file to be seen on browser through http:localhost:8080/"somePath".

I tried adding the line : Context docBase="C:/Users/abc/tomcat/webapps" path="/static" />
to server.xml and tried to hit the URL :
 http:localhost:8080/static/file.json but I am getting 404 not found.

Answer (score 1):

Better not define `Context` nodes in `server.xml`: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context

Instead create a file

```
$CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/static.xml
```

So in your case I suppose that is:

```
C:/Users/abc/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/static.xml
```

And put a `Context` node in it:

```
<Context path="/static/"
         docBase="C:/Users/abc/tomcat/webapps/static_files/">
</Context>
```

Here the json file is in a subdirectory `static_files`. I wouldn't expose the entire `webapps` directory to the `static` path. `docBase` need not even be in `webapps`, it could point to a directory anywhere on your filesystem.

Reboot and your json file will be available at

```
http:localhost:8080/static/file.json
```